# How to configure the “dotenv gem” in the rails 7 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, dotenv

How to configure the “dotenv gem” in the rails 7 application for the set environment variable.

Comment: is this an answer? also the **.env** variable assignment works but the example shown is in the **key=value** format

Comment: This is what worked for me  @Haumer You can put your solution in the comment if you have anything need to change in this, Thanks.

Comment: I was just confused because you initially didnt post a question but just an answer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add the below line in the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now', groups: [:development]
```

Run `bundle install`
Add the below code just below this line `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in the **application.rb**

```
# Load dotenv only in development or test environment
if ['development', 'test'].include? ENV['RAILS_ENV']
Dotenv::Railtie.load
end
```

Create one file in the app folder with `.env` name
Add your credentials in this `.env` file like below

```
DB_USERNAME: username
DB_PASSWORD: password
```

Use this env variable in the appropriate place like below.
in the `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Now your ENV variable setup is done. you can check it from the rails console like below.

```
rails c
> ENV["DB_USERNAME"]
> username
>ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]
> password
```

Comment: This won’t work, FYI.

You’re only pulling this into the `development` group via your `Gemfile` snippet. If people are looking to copy-paste this, make sure you’re including it in all the environments you want (i.e., in your `application.rb` file you reference the `test` environment, which undoubtedly has its own group in the `Gemfile`).

Answer (score 2):

Most of what Pooja is saying is effectively incorrect. The .env file goes into the root of your application, not in the app folder. The syntax of the env vars in .env are delimited with "=" not ": ". For example, a .env would look like this, which similar to how it is done in Node apps:

```
MYSQL_USERNAME=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_HOST=host
```

In her snippet above, she only includes the development block in Gemfile, yet performs a check on both development and test in application.rb when loading dotenv. In that case, the Gemfile should look like this and preferably add the gem to the top:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
```

In fact, everything I am saying is fundamentally taken from the Gem home page: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv